# Which values can be for $\dim(U+W)$ and $\dim(U \cap W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm given $\dim (V)=6$, $\dim (U)=3$, $\dim (W)=3$.

Which values can be for $\dim(U+W)=m$ and $\dim(U \cap W)=k$?

I tried to start from:
$$\dim(U+W)=  \dim (U) + \dim (W) - \dim(U \cap W)$$
$$m=3+3-k$$
$$m+k=6$$

What is the next step?

Comment: You're not really going to be able to solve it explicitly. There are multiple possible values for $m$ and $k$. What you need to do is think about how $$U + W \ge U \ge U \cap W$$ and similarly for $W$. So, $m \ge 3 \ge k$. That will help narrow the possibilities down. Other than that, you'll need to construct examples!

Comment: @TheoBendit so according to you explain the possible values are: $(m,k)=(3,3) or (4,2) or (5,1) or (6,0) $?

Comment: All possibilities must be found from this list, it's true. But unfortunately, our arguments so far don't guarantee that all these pairs are possibilities! What you should do, to properly guarantee that these are all the possibilities is to construct examples. For example, if $V = \mathbb{R}^6$ and $$U = W = \mathbb{R}^3 \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace^3 \le V,$$ then $(m, k) = (3, 3)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dim(U+W)$ can be any integer from $3$ to $6$; once you have it, the dimension of $U\cap W$ can be computed via Grassmann’s formula.

Consider a basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6\}$ and $U=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. Let $W_k=\operatorname{span}\{v_{1+k},v_{2+k},v_{3+k}\}$ for $0\le k\le 3$.